# obj Reference in C# and in vb

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
 Public Function DBToID(ByVal strValue As Object) As Integer
        If strValue Is DBNull.Value Then Return -1
        If strValue = "-1" Then Return -1
        Return CInteger(strValue)

    End Function
```

I am trying to convert this code in C# and I did this

```
public static int DBToID(object strValue)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(strValue, DBNull.Value))
            return -1;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(strValue,"-1"))
            return -1; 
        return CInteger(strValue.ToString());

    }
```

I just need to know whether I am doing it right or not as before I was doing

```
 public static int DBToID(object strValue)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(strValue, DBNull.Value))
            return -1;
        if (strValue == "-1")
            return -1; 
        return CInteger(strValue.ToString());

    }
```

but it is saying Possible unintended reference comparison it is not giving any error just a green line under strValue=="-1".So please explain that object.referenceequals is correct or not .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int DBToID(object strValue)
{
    if (strValue == DBNull.Value || Convert.ToString(strValue) == "-1")
        return -1;

    return Convert.ToInt32(strValue);
}
```

Try this

Comment: `IsEmptyOrNull` requires a `String`-typed argument, your code won't compile because `strValue` is an `Object` instance. Your code also does not check for the `DBNull.Value` value.

Comment: @raghav This may sound stupid but i would also just check for null, there is a difference between DBNull.Value and null. Also if you program permits I would alter it so it forces you to supply the actual type instead of accepting object.

Answer (score 1):

When the == operator is used to compare two strings, the Equals method is called, which checks for the equality of the contents of the strings rather than the references themselves. For instance, "hello".Substring(0, 4)=="hell" is true, even though the references on the two sides of the operator are different (they refer to two different string objects, which both contain the same character sequence).

Note that operator overloading only works here if both sides of the operator are string expressions at compile time - operators aren't applied polymorphically. If either side of the operator is of type object as far as the compiler is concerned, the normal == operator will be applied, and simple reference equality will be tested.

Taken from [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)

The code you've written is not wrong per se. The linked post/snippet should help with any confusion for how strings work. Unless you know what you are doing explicitly, using `ReferenceEquals` is a bad idea and I would use one of the other by-value check methods.

Comment: Good ole John Skeet!

Answer (score 1):

In C#, when the first operand of the `==` operator is cast as a reference-type (without any operator-overloading) then the `==` operator maps to the `Object.ReferenceEquals` operation. For the string-equality operation to be performed both operands must be known at compile-time to be `String` instances.

The most succinct (and safe) conversion would be this:

```
public Int32 DbToId(Object value) {
    Int32 ret;
    return value == DBNull.Value                                          ?  -1 :
           Int32.TryParse( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, value, out ret ) ? ret :
           -1;
}
```

...which is a shorter form of this:

```
public Int32 DbToId(Object value) {
    if( Object.ReferenceEquals( value, DBNull.Value ) ) return -1;
    Int32 ret;
    if( Int32.TryParse( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, value, out ret ) ) return ret;
    return -1; // fallback, base-case
}
```

Generally, try to avoid using VB.NET functions in C# (like `CInteger`) or the `Convert.ToXXX` methods as it is not immediately obvious what or how the conversion will work. Also avoid `ToString` calls with no arguments for the same reason. Prefer `TryParse` with appropriate `IFormatInfo` overloads.

Answer (score 0):

If you call '.ToString()' on the object, then your second condition should work fine:

```
public int DBToID(object strValue)
{
    if (strValue == DBNull.Value)
        return -1;
    if (strValue.ToString() == "-1")
        return -1;

    return System.Convert.ToInt32(strValue);
}
```

Comment: hi but giving .ToString() here shows the same thing green line with that message  Possible unintended reference comparison

Comment: I'm using VS 2015 and I don't get that green line - we probably have different options set.